# Solr relevant Boosting

Tags: search, solr, lucene, search-engine, solaris

I have various  field like name,location, landmark. If I search for any keyword and it hits name field much more than location then I want to boost name more that location. Again if it hits location more then I want to boost location more. Can you please give any solution or close by solution.

Comment: I may misunderstand you, but if you are saying you want to weigh the field that has the greatest number of matches for a query more heavily, that's certainly what Lucene's default scoring already does.

Comment: Please could you elaborate with an example. I don't understand why do you want to boost "field:location" when the query matches more with the same field!!! than the other??

Comment: I want to make dynamic boosting according to the hits of a particular keyword to a field i.e if the keyword hits landmark more than location then I boost more to landmark.